# How to observe array's single elements in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say that I have a class Employee whose picture property can be observed.

```
internal class Employee: CustomDebugStringConvertible, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    internal let name: String
    internal let role: Role
    @Published internal var picture: UIImage?
}
```

With a class that stores an array of employees. This array might be mutated later so it's a @Published property:

```
internal class EmployeeStorage: ObservableObject {
    @Published internal private(set) var employees: [Employee]
}
```

Now I have a list of views that uses the employee storage:

```
struct EmployeeList: View {
    @ObservedObject var employeeStorage = EmployeeStorage.sharedInstance

    var body: some View {
        // Uses employeeStorage.employee property to draw itself
    }
}
```

And the list is used in a content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var employeeStorage = EmployeeStorage.sharedInstance

    var body: some View {
        // Uses an EmployeeList value
    }
}
```

Let's say that now the EmployeeStorage object changes mutates employee array: this effectively updates the UI and I can see that the list is updated with the new collection of employees. Problem: what if I want to achieve the same effect when an employee's picture property changes? I thought that this was enough, but in my case (I have a more complex example), the UI is not updated in case that an employee's image changes. How to do it?

Comment: Your `ContentView` has a comment that mentions `EmployeeList` but you haven’t defined an `EmployeeList` type. What is an `EmployeeList`? Is `ContentView` supposed to display all the employees in an `EmployeeStorage`, or just a single `Employee`, or something else? If it’s only supposed to display a single `Employee`, why does it need the entire `EmployeeStorage`?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

- `Employee` Model

  - Your model should be a struct.
  - It does not need to conform to `ObservableObject`.
  - Why you're using `UIImage`!? Simply use `Image` and possibly a URL if you're fetching data from a web Api asynchronously.
  - something like:

  ```
  // Employee Model
  struct Employee: Codable, Identifiable {
      let name: String
      let role: Role
      let imageUrl: String
      let picture: Image
  }
  ```
- `EmployeeStorage`

  - I suspect that the way you're using `EmployeeStorage` as a singleton is problematic. Apple suggests that you better use an `@EnvironmentObject` property to pass data shared between views and their subviews. It's super simple, yet robust!

That being said, you can modify your code as follows:

```swift
// Employees Store
final class EmployeeStorage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var employees: [Employee]
}

// Content View
struct ContentView: View {
    var employeeStorage = EmployeeStorage()

    var body: some View {
        ...
        EmployeeList()
        .environmentObject(employeeStorage) // here you pass the storage to the list
    }
}

// Employee List
struct EmployeeList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var employeeStorage: EmployeeStorage

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(employeeStorage.employees) { employee in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EmployeeDetail()
                                .environmentObject(employeeStorage) 
                        ) {
                            EmployeeRow(employee: employee)
                        }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Employees"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) out. It's been done pretty much what you're going to achieve.